# How to control which version of Ruby gets used when running bundle

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

In ~/src/project/ containing all the files, I'm attempting to run `bundle` and `bundle install`, but it tells me I need a gem called "buff-extensions" and that gem installer requires Ruby version >= 2.2.0 to work properly.

When I ran `ruby --version`, it said Ruby 2.2.4p230 is being used when run from that directory.

I know there are several versions of Ruby on the machine in several places, and I'm struggling to follow the paths and figure out which technology is using which piece.

Comment: Your question is broad. I'd recommend removing the line about the other technologies and write a concise question specifically about that problem as it's a can of worms.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am unsure about exactly how much context is needed for someone to offer an answer, so I just included as much as I could possibly think of.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bundler docs](http://bundler.io/v1.14/gemfile.html) spell this out:

> You can specify the required version of Ruby in the `Gemfile` with `ruby`. If the `Gemfile` is loaded on a different Ruby version, Bundler will raise an exception with an explanation.

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

> What this means is that this app has a dependency to a Ruby VM that is ABI compatible with 1.9.3. If the version check does not match, Bundler will raise an exception. This will ensure the running code matches. You can be more specific with the `:engine` and `:engine_version` options.

```
ruby '1.9.3', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '1.6.7'
```

Comment: I tried this, putting "ruby '2.2.4'" in the Gemfile, and it tells me the same error message that the docs say I would get,  "Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.4".  It seems like the Gemfile line is being taken as a preference rather than a command.  I tried reading through more of those docs, specifically the page, and its follow-up links, you posted... if there be some way to resolve this in those docs, I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the exact incantation in order to get the intended result, and I now realize the situation is unreasonable to expect any stranger to attempt to answer.

It involved [chef](https://www.chef.io/), and I was supposed to run `chef exec bundle`.

Comment: :-) That's how we learn. And how we learn to work with SO. Once you've gone through the cycle a couple times it starts to make sense how to define a question and all the information that's needed. I like Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and "[Rubber Duck Problem Solving](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)".